# Replace element with a list in python

Tags: python, list

In python, what is the best way to replace an element in a list with the elements from another list?

For example, I have:

```
a = [ 1, 'replace_this', 4 ]
```

I want to replace `replace_this` with `[2, 3]`. After replacing it must be:

```
a = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
```

**Update**

Of course, it is possible to do with slicing (I'm sorry that I didn't write it in the question), but the problem is that it is possible that you have more than one `replace_this` value in the list. In this case you need to do the replacement in a loop and this becomes unoptimal.

I think that it would be better to use `itertools.chain`, but I'm not sure.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: I've updated with an example of using a replacement dictionary and `chain`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can just use slicing:

```
>>> a = [ 1, 'replace_this', 4 ]
>>> a[1:2] = [2, 3]
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

And as @mgilson points out - if you don't happen to know the position of the element to replace, then you can use `a.index` to find it... (see his comment)

**update related to not using slicing**

Using `itertools.chain`, making sure that `replacements` has iterables:

```
from itertools import chain

replacements = {
    'replace_this': [2, 3],
    4: [7, 8, 9]
}

a = [ 1, 'replace_this', 4 ]
print list(chain.from_iterable(replacements.get(el, [el]) for el in a))
# [1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: +1 -- And you can get the `1:2` via `i = a.index('replace_this'); a[i:i+1] = [2,3]`

Comment: This solution is really beautiful! Thank you very much for it

Answer (score 1):

I would go with a generator to replace the elements, and another generator to [flatten](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python) it. Assuming you have a working `flatten` generator, such that in the link provided:

```
def replace(iterable, replacements):
    for element in iterable:
        try:
            yield replacements[element]
        except KeyError:
            yield element

replac_dict = {
    'replace_this': [2, 3],
    1: [-10, -9, -8]
}
flatten(replace(a, replac_dict))
# Or if you want a list
#list(flatten(replace(a, replac_dict)))
```

Comment: The problem is if you have nested lists that will not work. But anyway, +1

Comment: You didn't mention you had nested lists. And, in fact, also the other solution does not work with nested lists.